# I would like to ask how to configure the automatic brightness change function in AOD scenes on Android U

Tags: android, brightness, doze, always-on-display

`    
true

```
<!-- Control whether the always on display mode is enabled by default. This value will be used
     during initialization when the setting is still null. -->
<bool name="config_dozeAlwaysOnEnabled">false</bool>`
```

这些仅仅可以打开AOD的功能，但是想请问怎么在AOD的场景自动变化亮度？因为现在一般手机在AOD场景都需要支持多个亮度
eg:2,10,30,60Nit
These can only enable AOD functions, but may I ask how to automatically change brightness in AOD scenes? Because nowadays, most smartphones need to support multiple brightness levels in AOD scenarios

Eg: 2,10,30,60Nit

I would like to request help. Can you tell me how to configure and enable or implement this feature